# Using google sheets, is there a way to filter for multiple ranges and multiple conditions?

Tags: google-sheets, checkbox

Update: Got the solution I needed, so making the spreadsheet private again, thank you!

I have a spreadsheet with multiple sheets that all have static info in column A and checkboxes in columns D (fix) and E (buy). I want to be able to check the fix and or buy boxes on any of the sheets and have the info from column A in the same row populate onto sheet 1 so I have a master list of items that need to be fixed and items that need to be bought (two different columns, one for fix, one for buy)

I know I can use this formula =filter('sheet2'!A:A,'sheet2'!E:E) to get the info off of one sheet, but I'm wondering how to do this with multiple and populate the info to the same list on sheet 1. I tried using {} brackets to introduce multiple ranges, but to no avail. Perhaps I did not enter it correctly though?

Is there a way to use the filter formula with multiple ranges and multiple conditions? Is there a better formula to use?

Comment: So, you want to stack buy and fix to sheet1 from all other sheet?

Comment: `Got the solution I needed` That's good to hear. Why not post your solution as an answer (or at least disclose the answer) so that it can benefit future users.

Comment: `so making the spreadsheet private again, thank you!` StackOverflow aims to help users who _ask_ a question as well as those who come _looking for answers_. If a question relies on a user opening a spreadsheet to better understand a scenario, then the absence of that spreadsheet affects the value of the question. For future reference, questions needs to stand on their own. Information about the structure or content of data in a spreadsheet needs to be included in the body of a question.  Please don't assume that users can/will/should open your spreadsheet to better understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to list all sheet name in a cell. For my answer I listed sheet names to `F2` cell then down. Then use following formulas. For `Buy/Acquire`.

```
=QUERY(REDUCE("Buy/Acquire",F2:F8,LAMBDA(a,x,VSTACK(a,QUERY(INDIRECT("'" & x & "'!A:E"),"select A where E =TRUE",0)))),"where Col1 is not null",0)
```

For `Make/Fix`

```
=QUERY(REDUCE("Make/Fix",F2:F8,LAMBDA(a,x,VSTACK(a,IFERROR(QUERY(INDIRECT("'" & x & "'!A:E"),"select A where D =TRUE",0)),""))),"where Col1 is not null",0)
```

[image]